# SQL Column Swap Behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, swap

I'm swapping column values in a table using the following statement:

```
UPDATE SwapTable
SET ValueA=ValueB
   ,ValueB=ValueA
```

This works and the values do get swapped, as can be verified by this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc36a/2).

However, if we did such thing in (mostly any) other language, we would end up with both `ValueA` and `ValueB` having identical values.

So my question is why/how this works in SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just see the execution plan.

1. Select all the rows from the table and make it as a row set.
2. Open a transaction
3. Update the table referenced (SwapTable) with corresponding row address, from **the old values read from the row set** to **the field reference**.
4. Commit -- done updating.

Comment: You have got my question wrong. My question is, if ValueA=ValueB, then when it attempts ValueB=ValueA, both columns should have the same value(s), but the values are actually swapped. WHY?

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR  because NOTHING is changed BEFORE COMMIT. In your second statement `ValueB=ValueA` the old (unchanged) value is used.

Comment: yeah, what I meant was exactly same as valex. In your statement "ValueB=ValueA", ValueB is field referece - the target; not a value, ValueA is comming from the row set - the actual value; not the target. And the row set is freezed after fetched from the table. No problem at all before and after the commit line.